# Java annotation based validation io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema

Tags: openapi, hibernate-validator, swagger-3.0

Now swagger3(openApi) now is current used. And based on the annotations defined in the library swagger-annoations:2.1.10 and package "io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations", api doc is easily to generator.

But now the springboot validation of request/response are implemented by the hibernator-validtor. and the hibernator-validtor use the annotation defined in the package "javax.validation.constraints"

If any tools that validate the request/response based on the annotation defined by the class in the package "io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations", for example, io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Schema.
In the class io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Schema, it already defines many validate descriptions.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SomCM.png)